# Spring mongodb how to use crudRespository with embedded documents

Tags: schema, spring-data-mongodb

Why when I created crudRespository to do search on embedded object do none of the queries work and all of them return null. Is there something I'm doing wrong? There is an example.
I hope this is not a limitation of the spring mongodb. Maybe you know a different way to extract embedded object? I could use @DbRef but I read that it is not recommended for the performance issues.

Country.class

```
@Document(collection="countries")
@TypeAlias("ctry")
public class Country {

@Id private BigInteger id;

private String name;

private Continent continent;

public Country(String name, Continent continent) {
    setName(name);
    setContinent(continent);
}
  //get/set omitted 
}
```

Embedded document  Continent.class

```
public final class Continent {

private final long id;
private final String name;

public Continent(long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

//get/set omitted 

}
```

ContinentRespository.class - this works fine the data is returned as it should

```
public interface CountryRepository extends Repository<Country, BigInteger> {

//------------------------------------------- equality

public Country findByName(String countryName);

@Query("{name : ?0}")
public Country findByNameQuery(String countryName);

}
```

ContinentRespository.class - all the methods always return null :/

```
public interface ContinentRepository extends CrudRepository<Continent, Long> {

public Continent findByName(String name);

@Query("{name : ?0}")
public Continent findByNameQuery(String name);

 }
```

RespositoryTest.class - test class testFindEmbeddedContinent fails because returned object is null. testFindDocumentCountry works as expected

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MongoConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class RepositoryTest {

@Autowired private CountryRepository countryRepository;
@Autowired private ContinentRepository continentRepo;
@Autowired private MongoOperations mongoOps;
@Autowired private MongoTemplate template;

@Before
public void reset() {
    DBCollection countries = template.getCollection("countries");
    countries.drop();

    countries.insert(dbObjectFromJson("{ '_id' : '8', '_class' : 'ctry', 'name' : 'Japan', 'continent' : { '_id' : 2, 'name' : 'Asia' } }"));
}

@Test
public void testFindEmbeddedContinent() {
    Continent asia = continentRepo.findByName("Asia");
    assertNotNull(asia);
    assertThat(asia.getName(), is(equalTo("Asia")));
}

@Test
public void testFindDocumentCountry() {
    Country japan = countryRepository.findByName("Japan");
    assertNotNull(japan);
    assertThat(japan.getContinent().getName(), is(equalTo("Asia")));
    assertThat(japan.getName(), is(equalTo("Japan")));
}

private static DBObject dbObjectFromJson(String json) {
    return (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A repository - by definition - mimics a collection of aggregate roots. In MongoDB this translates into top-level documents of a collection. Thus, you can only create repositories for top-level documents, i.e. `Country` in your case.

Im an not totally sure that it makes sense that a `Continent` is a property of a `Country` (as usually a country is part of a continent) but that might just be due to the sample. If you want to query `Continents` independently, make them a top-level document and keep references to the country either using simple ID or a DBRef (the former recommended).

Comment: Thanks Oliver. Yes the sample is just a quick example. You answer explains it all thanks. Should I truly have to by worried about performance using the DBRef? Everywhere I read says not to use it :/